# Excalibur and Calibur in fate stay night, which one is King Arthur using in history?

Tags: fate-stay-night, fate-zero

So in fate stay night Saber her Noble Phantom is called "Excalibur" which is the same name as her sword. But when Shiro trace the Excalibur, it turns out that is the one that Saber lost forever.

So my question is, did King Arthur in History own two sword called Excalibur and Calibur?

Comment: Well King Arthur is a fictional character, so there is no real history here. In fiction, it depends on whose story or opinion you read. For some Caliburn and Excalibur are the same. For others, as in Type Moon, Caliburn is the sword in the stone, and Excalibur is from the lady in the lake.

Comment: This question is about history (or at least non-anime/manga fictional story), not anime.

Comment: Related question on [Scifi](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73175/where-did-king-arthur-get-his-sword-excalibur) about King Arthur and Excalibur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no "history" to speak of, as the tale of Arthur and Excalibur is fictional.

Otherwise, after looking at the [Excalibur article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excalibur) on wikipedia, it appears that:

- The Sword in the Stone is the sword that proves Arthur's right to rule after Uther Pendragon;
- Caliburn is always an alternate name for Excalibur;
- According to the [Vulgate Cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lancelot-Grail) (A 13th-century set of poems in french), Excalibur is explicitly identified as the Sword in the Stone;
- According to the [Post-Vulgate Cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-Vulgate_Cycle) (A revision of the Vulgate Cycle, with a lot of changes), Excalibur is the sword given by the Lady of the Lake, and was returned to her after Arthur's passing;
- Thomas Malory later compiled a number of Arthurian legends in his 1485 compilation called [Le Morte D'Arthur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Morte_d%27Arthur). In it, he mentions both versions of Excalibur's origin. Thomas Malory's work has been the main source for many modern Arthurian authors;

In the end, Excalibur is the Sword in the Stone in some versions of the story, and in other versions it is not. In Fate/Stay Night, the latter option was chosen.

However, the act of using the name "Caliburn" for a sword distinct from "Excalibur" seems uncommon. I suspect however that it is done so that it can be referred to by name instead of always having to call it "The Sword in the Stone".

Comment: In the Nasuverse, [Caliburn](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Caliburn) is the original sword (eluding the one inside The Gate of Babylon). [Excalibur](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Excalibur) and [Avalon](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Avalon) (which gained the properties of Cliburn) were created after it.

Comment: sorry about that I dont know actually this is a fantasy tale D:: but thanks for answering this stupid question anyway!